# How to force quit non responsive wifi dialog

Tags: macos, mac, wifi, force-quit

I have two non responsive wifi dialogs.

[image]

They don't go away with cancel, and they don't offer the join option.

They don't appear in the activity monitor.

I don't know what the process is called, I tried killing every process with the word Wifi on it, and Wifi proxies.

Any way to solve other than full, reboot/logout?

Comment: yeah, I *really* loath those pop-ups, though the "fix" is to boot into recovery and disable the responsible application (I don't much use such wifi networks, so this works for me...)

Answer (score 1):

This applescript works for me using the latest version of Sierra

You can paste this code into ScriptEditor app and save it as an application.  Then run your new app anytime you need it

```
do shell script "killall SystemUIServer"
```